# Basis of a matrix with zero rows

Tags: matrices, matlab

I'm trying to check whether B is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$. If B is not a basis, I want to use the matrix eye(m) from matlab to create a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$ that will contain all vectors from B and some vectors from the matrix eye(m). I don't have issue with the matlab function coding, I have issue with what the right answer should be. For example: The matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\ 0 &0\\ 0 & 0\\ 0 &1\end{bmatrix}$  turns into what? Does it turn into this:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 &0 &0\\0 &0 &1 &0\\0 &0& 0 &1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
or this:
$\begin{bmatrix}1 &0\\ 0 &1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: It should turn into the first choice if you represent vectors by column vectors.

Comment: Are you sure? The post has been edited. I'm worried you may have the matrix dimensions backwards..

Comment: I am sure about my answer. What I'm not sure is whether you use column vectors or row vectors. It is, however, more common to use column vectors in most text so that matrix multiplication would go on the left of a vector.

Comment: They are in columns

Comment: Then you have had my answer from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

A rectangular matrix has a left and a right basis. Both can be completed to an orthogonal set (gram-schmidt or something similar).

If you want to understand this better, take a look at the SVD decomposition. It does precisely that (and more): it presents a rectangular matrix as a succession of three transformations: decomposition in the right basis, scale in this basis, and mapping to the vectors of the left basis:

$$A=U\Sigma V^T$$

where $U$ and $T$ are orthonormal.

Comment: I just need to know if the first or second possible answer is correct.

Comment: Depends what you mean by that. As said, a rectangular matrix maps from one space to another space of different dimension: each has its own basis! You have to specify if your basis vectors are in rows or columns of your matrix. You take the one that hase the same dimension as your vectors.

Comment: they are in columns

Comment: Then extend to 4x4 and you have a complete basis for a 4-dimensional space which include your initial two vectors.